# Understanding Abstract Base Classes in Python

Tags: python, oop, abstract-class, abc

I was reading about abstract base class and came across https://www.python-course.eu/python3_abstract_classes.php website. I got general idea about them but I found two statement contradictory of each other.

> Subclasses of an abstract class in Python are not required to implement abstract methods of the parent class.

and

> A class that is derived from an abstract class cannot be instantiated unless all of its abstract methods are overridden.

My understanding of first statement is, derived class are not required to implement abstract method of the parent class which is wrong. I made a sample program to check that.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractClassExample(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self):
        print("Some implementation!")

class AnotherSubclass(AbstractClassExample):

    def just_another_method(self):
        super().do_something()
        print("The enrichment from AnotherSubclass")

x = AnotherSubclass() # TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class AnotherSubclass with abstract methods do_something
x.do_something()
```

I would like an explanation of what the first statement means(preferably with examples).

Comment: Your code demonstrates the first statement, doesn't it? If you delete `x = AnotherSubclass()`, then your code will run without error.

Comment: If I remove that then there is nothing running in the program, so there won't be any error. My point is for `AnotherSubclass ` to be instantiated we must have to implement the `do_something` method, and I think first statement contradicts that

Comment: @Sweeper oh I think I got it now, we can make the class, but not instantiate it?

Comment: Exactly! That is what the first statement says. Note that this is more subtle than "the program does nothing so of course no error!" because if you, say, try to remove some empty spaces at the start of lines you'll get errors even if your program "does nothing".

Comment: Yep, your second comment got it. I will post an answer.

Comment: So it is more like `Subclasses of an abstract class in Python are not required to implement abstract methods of the parent class, but if you don't override then you won't be able to instantiate it.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code demonstrates that the second statement is true. It doesn't show that the first statement is false.

In your code, you are trying to *instantiate* `AnotherSubclass`, which is not allowed because `AnotherSubclass` does not implement all the abstract methods. The second statement says this.

However, if you delete the last two lines, i.e. not instantiating `AnotherSubclass`, then your code will produce no errors when you try to run it. This shows that the first statement is true - subclasses of abstract classes that doesn't implement all its abstract methods *are allowed to exist*.

You can write another subclass of `AnotherSubclass` called `YetAnotherClass`, this time implementing the abstract method, and you will be able to instantiate `YetAnotherClass`. Note that your program now does something, and `AnotherSubclass` is still allowed to exist.